# What does this line stand for

Tags: javascript

As i am beginner I was practicing on marks grading project. I went through a code written on a website But i am not able to understand one line that what does **students[i][1]** stand for in this code. Kindly make me understand clearly.

```
var students = [['David', 80], ['Vinoth', 77], ['Divya', 88], ['Ishitha', 95], ['Thomas', 68]];

 var Avgmarks = 0;

 for (var i=0; i < students.length; i++) {
    Avgmarks += students[i][1];
    var avg = (Avgmarks/students.length);
     }

    console.log("Average grade: " + (Avgmarks)/students.length);

    if (avg < 60){
      console.log("Grade : F");      
      } 
    else if (avg < 70) {
            console.log("Grade : D"); 
              } 
    else if (avg < 80) 
         {
            console.log("Grade : C"); 
    } else if (avg < 90) {
            console.log("Grade : B"); 
    } else if (avg < 100) {
            console.log("Grade : A"); 
    }
```

Comment: It refers to the number in each array `students` contains.

Comment: Search for "multidimensional array"

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to access the marks of each individual student in the students array.

[i] = the current iteration of the for loop
[1] = 2nd element in the current student array which is marks in the example.

so Avgmarks += students[i][1] is actually adding up all the marks for all the students in the students array